# What is the fastest Java collection with the basic functionality of a Queue?

Tags: java, performance, collections

What is the fastest collection in Java?

I only need the operations to add and remove, order is not important, equals elements is not a issue, nothing more than add and remove is imporant.

Without limit size is important too.

These collection will have Objects inside him.

Currently I'm using ArrayDeque because I see this is the faster Queue implementation.

Comment: If order is not important, you're not looking for a queue.

Comment: Currently I'm adding in the final and retrieving from the start(like a Queue) , but if I can take out all the elements, one by one, I can use another Collection.

Comment: "...premature optimization is the root of all evil"

Comment: choosing the right collection is not premature optimization.

Comment: It's a webcrawler for a second project, so velocity is an important item here.

Comment: If it's a webcrawler it will be network-bound: performance of the queue will be practically irrelevant.

Comment: Yes, I know, but is better guarantee that the bound is the network and not my application.

Comment: BoltClock, that is incorrect for a capital-Q Queue in Java. It means only "a mutable collection with a head element". Reread java.util.Queue.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

`ArrayDeque` is best. See [this benchmark](http://microbenchmarks.appspot.com/run/limpbizkit@gmail.com/com.publicobject.blog.TreeListBenchmark), which comes from [this blog post](https://publicobject.com/2010/07/07/caliper_confirms_reality_linked_list_vs_array_list/) about the results of benchmarking this. `ArrayDeque` doesn't have the overhead of node allocations that `LinkedList` does nor the overhead of shifting the array contents left on remove that `ArrayList` has. In the benchmark, it performs about **3x** as well as `LinkedList` for large queues and even slightly better than `ArrayList` for empty queues. For best performance, you'll probably want to give it an initial capacity large enough to hold the number of elements it's likely to hold at a time to avoid many resizes.

Between `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`, it seems that it depends on the average number of total elements the queue will contain at any given time and that `LinkedList` beats `ArrayList` starting at about 10 elements.

Comment: ArrayList used as stack should be same as ArrayDeque, the initial capacity greatly affect the performance. Too much means more memory to allocate and collect, too little means more copies (but imo it's overall better than too large for tight loops). I could not see the source of the benchmark, is it available?

Comment: @bestsss: Yes, used as a stack `ArrayList` would be approximately equivalent, though `ArrayDeque`'s javadoc suggests that it may be slightly faster. And yeah, given the requirements in the question, stack-like use would work fine. The benchmark was specifically for FIFO queue use though (you can see an example of the code in the linked blog post).

Comment: hmm. the benchmark is a bit flawed towards LinkedList though (The entire test runs in the young gen and in the memory cache). ArrayDeque is also properly sized (no resize in the loop either) and the size remains the same. I can't even think of a single good use of a queue where the queue stays full. But yeah, the resuls are to be expected. Side note: the doc of ArrayDeque lists java.util.Stack (extends Vector) to be slower not ArrayList, However, indeed it can be better than ArrayList since there is no explicit modCount support and no explicit range checks.

Comment: @bestsss: Obviously it's often going to be the case that a queue doesn't stay full, but the benchmark is basically testing the performance of a single add and remove when the queue is at a range of different sizes, so it covers that. Also, it's reasonable that the `ArrayDeque` doesn't resize since A) sizing it properly is an option in real uses and B) resizes will be vanishingly rare in any long-term use of a queue. Microbenchmarks will never be perfect, but I think that one is pretty good. And yes, I did misremember the `ArrayDeque` javadoc... oops!

Comment: no need to remember the docs I guess. Just to remember that cyclic arrays make the best practical queues, unless you need lock-free concurrency. It's just a shame how much better CLQ is than LinkedList.

Comment: I realise this question is old, but both your links are dead. Are there any alternative URLs?

Comment: @rath: Sorry, I have no idea where you could find either. It may be that if you scroll far enough back on https://publicobject.com/ you could find the blog post.

Comment: Since I had the same problem as @rath, I crawled the original blog and I found the original article: [https://publicobject.com/2010/07/07/caliper_confirms_reality_linked_list_vs_array_list/](https://publicobject.com/2010/07/07/caliper_confirms_reality_linked_list_vs_array_list/).

Unfortunately, if I try to see the benchmark results, I get a 401 - unauthorized error.

Comment: Here is also another experiment that confirms that ArrayDeque is 3x faster than LinkedList: http://java-performance.info/linkedlist-performance/

Comment: Can someone tell me why `ArrayDeque doesn't have overhead of shifting the array contents` as Colin mentioned? ArrayDeque is still an **array**, so if I remove head, all elements need to be shifted to the left, correct? That answer surprised me..

Comment: @Stefan No, removing the head just requires moving the index of the head one to the right. It's not an `ArrayList` where the first element is always at index `0`.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a `java.util.LinkedList` - it's doubly-linked and cicrular, so adding to one end and taking from the other are O(1)

Whatever implementation you choose, refer to it by the `Queue` interface, so that you can easily change it if it turns out not to fit your case (if, of course, a queue is what you need in the first place)

Update: Colin's answer shows a benchmark that concludes that `ArrayDeque` is better. Both have O(1) operations, but `LinkedList` creates new objects (nodes), which slightly affect performance. Since both have O(1) I don't think it would be too wrong to choose `LinkedList` though.

Comment: `ArrayDeque` is objectively better though.

Comment: @ColinD - I saw, but why? Due to object creation (nodes) in the linekdlist? Both seem to be O(1)

Comment: @Bohzo: Yeah, the object creation in `LinkedList` impacts both time and memory performance.

Comment: @ColinD @Bozho So does the array resizing in ArrayDeque. The real consideration here is the algorithmic complexity. Anything involving an array is O(N) for add/delete, anything involving links is O(1).

Comment: @EJP: `ArrayDeque` _is_ O(1) for add and remove on the front/end (i.e. when used as a queue or stack) because it's a circular array and doesn't copy anything in those cases. Additionally, resize is an occasional operation that can often be avoided with an appropriate initial capacity. `LinkedList`'s overhead of an additional object creation (plus garbage collection of that object) affects every add/remove on the queue. The benchmark I linked shows it to be consistently 3x as fast as a `LinkedList`.

Comment: @EJP, can you explain how exactly it's O(1) for delete? you have to iterate to find the element to delete it and iterating a LinkedList is terrible. ArrayList and ArrayDeque are an amortized O(1) for adds, nothing like O(n).

Comment: @bestsss It is O(1) for delete assuming you are already at the item to delete. The statement comes from the Javadoc.

Comment: Plus arrays will always outperform linked lists for bigger amount of small objects due to cache misses on processors. Linked lists are usually disjoint in memory , which is not a case with arrays.

Comment: `O(1) != O(1)`. `O()` is just a measure of complexity, not of execution time. An operation that always takes 5 years regardless of `n` is `O(1)`, as is an operation that always takes 5 ms. I'd rather use the one that takes 5 ms. Even an operation that takes 5 ms per element (which is `O(n)`) is going to be better than the 5 year operation if `n` doesn't get too big.

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom nobody questions that. And my update indicates that the O(1) in one case is faster. But given the relative similarity between the operations, the O-notation is an indication of speed, although it does denote complexity.

Answer (score 0):

ConcurrentLinkedDeque  is the best choice for multi thread  Queue