# Why is ArrayDeque better than LinkedList

Tags: java, deque, linked-list, arraydeque

I am trying to to understand **why Java's ArrayDeque is better than Java's LinkedList** as they both implement Deque interface.

I hardly see someone using ArrayDeque in their code. If someone sheds more light into how ArrayDeque is implemented, it would be helpful.

If I understand it, I will be more confident using it. I could not clearly understand the JDK implementation as to the way it manages head and tail references.

Comment: Look at the answer in this question I done days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129805/what-is-the-fastest-java-collection-with-the-basic-functionality-of-a-queue

Comment: In the folder, where you have your jdk installed, there is a file `src.zip`. It is the archive with the source code of java classes. I strongly recommend to study these classes structure and internals to get better understanding how do java classes work.

Comment: One more point. The default size of ArrayDeque is 16. ArrayDeque doubles its size when it is full. Elements are copied to the new array after the size doubles. It is better to initialize ArrayDeque with an initial size.

Comment: Another point worth mentioning is that on LinkedList you can use indexes to iterate through its elements while ArrayDeque does not support index based access.

Answer (score 248, accepted):

Linked structures are possibly the worst structure to iterate with a cache miss on each element. On top of it they consume way more memory.

If you need add/remove of the both ends, ArrayDeque is significantly better than a linked list. Random access each element is also O(1) for a cyclic queue.

The only better operation of a linked list is removing the current element during iteration.

Comment: Another difference to bear in mind: LinkedList supports null elements, whereas ArrayDeque does not.

Comment: Also another small disadvantage (for real-time applications) is that on a push/add operation it takes a bit more when the internal array of the ArrayDeque is full, as it has to double its size and copy all the data.

Comment: @AndreiI, this only one side of the story. Even if you exclude the iteration costs for real time application and ability to prealloc the needed capacity, the GC may need to iterate the entire LinkedList. Basically you are moving the costs (which are higher to boot) into the GC.

Comment: @bestsss why would adding/removing on the head be worse off for the LinkedList?

Comment: @DavidT. b/c it involves GC costs of the freed node, assigning the head may also require card marking (for the GC again, if the LinkedList is already in the tenured gen)... and that's on top of the extra indirection (cache-miss) to return the element and relink.

Comment: Also, `LinkedList` implements `List` while `ArrayDeque` doesn't. This means that `LinkedList` have methods like `indexOf` or `remove(int)` while `ArrayDeque` hasn't. It can be important sometimes.

Comment: kind late to this party. For `The only better operation of a linked list is removing the current element during iteration.` do u mean the method like `remove()` which remove the head of the queue? because linkedlist is also fail-fast.

Comment: @HuazheYin calling `remove()` on the `Iterator` or `ListIterator`…

Comment: Linked structures are possibly the worst structure to iterate with a cache miss on each element. -------what does it mean? What is a cache miss?

Comment: @ZhaoGang
`ArrayDeque` resemble arrays and allocate memory in contiguous memory blocks, in contrast to `LinkedList` where the memory allocation are in non-contiguous memory space. Since the data is stored in contiguous space, data will be stored in cache pretty easily. That would be a time consuming task for  `LinkedList` and hence chance for cache miss.

Comment: @bestsss isn't GC always linear time for both arrays and linked lists? It always needs to go through all the elements to know which ones were removed. Of course, due to cache locality and less indirection, iterating over the array would be faster, but both operations are O(N).

Comment: "If you need add/remove of the both ends, ArrayDeque is significantly better than a linked list." - Time complexity wise, adding/removing from both ends is O(1) in either structures (amortized), but ArrayDeque could be more efficient production-wise as others have pointed out due to GC involvement when LinkedList has to create/release its internal nodes when adding/removing at both ends.

Answer (score 115):

I believe that the main performance bottleneck in `LinkedList` is the fact that whenever you push to any end of the deque, behind the scene the implementation allocates a new linked list node, which essentially involves JVM/OS, and that's expensive. Also, whenever you pop from any end, the internal nodes of `LinkedList` become eligible for garbage collection and that's more work behind the scene. 
Also, since the linked list nodes are allocated here and there, usage of CPU cache won't provide much benefit.

If it might be of interest, I have a proof that adding (appending) an element to `ArrayList` or `ArrayDeque` runs in amortized constant time; refer to [this](https://coderodde.wordpress.com/2015/08/01/keeping-vectors-efficient/).

Comment: Can you tell me how adding/removing element from head is better in Linked that in Array? Shouldn't LinkedList have advantage as only references to `prev` and `next` are changed, while in ArrayDeque many elements need to be shifted?

Answer (score 46):

All the people criticizing a `LinkedList`, think about every other guy that has been using  `List` in Java probably uses `ArrayList` and an `LinkedList` most of the times because they have been before Java 6 and because those are the ones being taught as a start in most books.

But, that doesn't mean, I would blindly take `LinkedList`'s or `ArrayDeque`'s side. If you want to know, take a look at the below benchmark [done by Brian](https://web.archive.org/web/20191101213733/http://brianandstuff.com/2016/12/12/java-arraydeque-vs-linkedlist/) (archived).

The test setup considers:

> - Each test object is a 500 character String. Each String is a    different object in memory.
> - The size of the test array will be varied during the tests.
> - For each array size/Queue-implementation combination, 100 tests are    run and average time-per-test is calculated.
> - Each tests consists of filling each queue with all objects, then    removing them all.
> - Measure time in terms of milliseconds.

Test Result:

> - Below 10,000 elements, both LinkedList and ArrayDeque tests averaged    at a sub 1 ms level.
> - As the sets of data get larger, the differences between the    ArrayDeque and LinkedList average test time gets larger.
> - At the test size of 9,900,000 elements, the LinkedList approach took    ~165% longer than the ArrayDeque approach.

Graph:

[image]

**Takeaway:**

- If your requirement is storing 100 or 200 elements, it wouldn't make
  much of a difference using either of the Queues.
- However, if you are developing on mobile, you may want to use an
  `ArrayList` or `ArrayDeque` with a good guess of maximum capacity
  that the list may be required to be because of strict memory constraint.
- A lot of code exists, written using a `LinkedList` so tread carefully when deciding to use a `ArrayDeque` especially because it **DOESN'T implement the `List` interface**(I think that's reason big enough). It may be that your codebase talks to the List interface extensively, most probably and you decide to jump in with an `ArrayDeque`. Using it for internal implementations might be a good idea...

Comment: How would this benchmark capture the GC time caused by the linked list  garbage?

Answer (score 37):

[ArrayDeque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) and [LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) are implementing [Deque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) interface but implementation is different.

Refer to [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/deque.html) for more details.

Key differences:

> 1. The *ArrayDeque* class is the resizable array implementation of the *Deque* interface and *LinkedList* class is the list implementation
> 2. NULL elements can be added to *LinkedList* but not in *ArrayDeque*
> 3. *ArrayDeque* is more efficient than the *LinkedList* for add and remove operation at both ends and LinkedList implementation is efficient for removing the current element during the iteration
> 4. The *LinkedList* implementation consumes more memory than the *ArrayDeque*

So if you don't have to support NULL elements && looking for less memory && efficiency of add/remove elements at both ends, *ArrayDeque* is the best

Comment: "In Linked list, it will take O(N) to find last element." is not exactly true. LinkedList is implemented as a doubly linked list so you don't have to traverse the list to get the last element (`header.previous.element`). The "memory efficiency" claim can also be challenged since the backing array is always resized to the next power of 2.

Comment: "It will take O(N) to find last element" is WRONG. Linked list keeps a reference to the last node and LinkedList.descendingIterator() get's that node. So we get O(1) performance. See: https://coffeeorientedprogramming.wordpress.com/2018/04/23/linkedlist-descendingiterator-run-time/
(thus downvoting).

Comment: When you use an `Iterator` to access the last element, the operation is O(N) for both classes. When you use the common `Deque` interface, accessing the last element is O(1) for both classes. Regardless of which point of view you take, attributing O(1) to `ArrayDeque` and O(N) to `LinkedList` at the same time, is wrong.

Comment: All your suggestions are taken and corrected the content

Answer (score 32):

`ArrayDeque` is new with Java 6, which is why a lot of code (especially projects that try to be compatible with earlier Java versions) don't use it.

It's "better" in some cases because you're not allocating a node for each item to insert; instead all elements are stored in a giant array, which is resized if it gets full.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think `ArrayDeque` is better than `LinkedList`.  They are different.

`ArrayDeque` is faster than `LinkedList` on average.  But for adding an element, `ArrayDeque` takes amortized constant time, and `LinkedList` takes constant time.

For time-sensitive applications that require all operations to take constant time, only `LinkedList` should be used.

`ArrayDeque`'s implementation uses arrays and requires resizing, and occasionally, when the array is full and needs to add an element, it will take linear time to resize, resulting the `add()` method taking linear time.  That could be a disaster if the application is very time-sensitive.

A more detailed explanation of Java's implementation of the two data structures is available in the "[Algorithms, Part I](https://www.coursera.org/learn/algorithms-part1)" course on Coursera offered by Princeton University, taught by Wayne and Sedgewick.  The course is free to the public.

The details are explained in the video "Resizing Arrays" in the "Stacks and Queues" section of "Week 2".

Answer (score 1):

although **`ArrayDeque<E>`** and **`LinkedList<E>`** have both implemented  **`Deque<E>`** Interface, but the ArrayDeque uses basically Object array **`E[]`** for keeping the elements inside its Object, so it generally uses index for locating the head and tail elements.

In a word, it just works like Deque (with all Deque's method), however uses array's data structure. As regards which one is better, depends on how and where you use them.

Answer (score 0):

That's not always the case.

For example, in the case below `linkedlist` has better performance than `ArrayDeque` according to leetcode 103.

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * public class TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode left;
 *     TreeNode right;
 *     TreeNode(int x) { val = x; }
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    public List<List<Integer>> zigzagLevelOrder(TreeNode root) {
        List<List<Integer>> rs=new ArrayList<>();
        if(root==null)
            return rs;
        //  here ,linkedlist works better
        Queue<TreeNode> queue=new LinkedList<>();
        queue.add(root);
        boolean left2right=true;
        while(!queue.isEmpty())
        {
            int size=queue.size();
            LinkedList<Integer> t=new LinkedList<>();
            while(size-->0)
            {
                TreeNode tree=queue.remove();
                if(left2right)  
                    t.add(tree.val);
                else
                    t.addFirst(tree.val);
                if(tree.left!=null)
                {
                    queue.add(tree.left);
                }
                if(tree.right!=null)
                {
                    queue.add(tree.right);
                }
            }
            rs.add(t);
            left2right=!left2right;
        }
        return rs;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how ArrayDeque is implemented, but I have implemented something similar in C++ years ago, and I'm quite sure they do the same.
the collection is actually an ArrayList which is considered "cyclic", i.e. the next item after a[n-1] is a[0].
the deque also keeps two pointers (integer) to the first and last item in the deque. When you addFirst you decread "first" (cyclic) and when addLast increase "last". It's quite simple and efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Another big not obvious advantage of using ArrayDeque is .clone() implementation.

for LinkedList it is traversing through the whole list in O(n):

```js
    /**
     * Returns a shallow copy of this {@code LinkedList}. (The elements
     * themselves are not cloned.)
     *
     * @return a shallow copy of this {@code LinkedList} instance
     */
    public Object clone() {
        LinkedList<E> clone = superClone();

        // Put clone into "virgin" state
        clone.first = clone.last = null;
        clone.size = 0;
        clone.modCount = 0;

        // Initialize clone with our elements
        for (Node<E> x = first; x != null; x = x.next)
            clone.add(x.item);

        return clone;
    }
```

and for the ArrayDeque we have System.arrayCopy() (if you dig deeper than Arrays.copyOf()) which is way more effective, it is probably linear too, but with way less inclination

```js
    /**
     * Returns a copy of this deque.
     *
     * @return a copy of this deque
     */
    public ArrayDeque<E> clone() {
        try {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            ArrayDeque<E> result = (ArrayDeque<E>) super.clone();
            result.elements = Arrays.copyOf(elements, elements.length);
            return result;
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            throw new AssertionError();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -6):

Time complexity for ArrayDeque for accessing a element is O(1) and that for LinkList is is O(N) to access last element. ArrayDeque is not thread safe so manually synchronization is necessary so that you can access it through multiple threads and so they they are faster.

Comment: If you are referring to `LinkedList` in Java's `Collection`, it is doubly linked and has fast access to the head and the tail, so access to the last element also takes O(1).

Comment: Accessing last element in LinkedList is not O(N). If you use descendingIterator(), it is performed in O(1). See https://coffeeorientedprogramming.wordpress.com/2018/04/23/linkedlist-descendingiterator-run-time/  (thus downvote).

Comment: Both classes are not thread-safe. And there is no connection between the beginning of the sentence “manually synchronization is necessary” and its end “they are faster”.