# How to do add all with java streams?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

How do I do add all with java 8 ?

```
processeditemList is a Map<Integer, Map<Item, Boolean>>
```

As for now I am doing :

```
List<Item> itemList = Lists.newLinkedList();
for (Map<Item, Boolean> entry : processeditemList.values()) {
    itemList.addAll(entry.keySet());
}
return itemList;
```

Comment: do you want to add the integer values in the processeditemList???

Comment: This code is perfectly valid in Java 8.

Comment: Just a side note: [Don’t use `LinkedList`, at least not without a strong reason](https://stackoverflow.com/q/322715/2711488).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use [flatMap](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/java_8_flatmap_example). It's used to combine multiple streams into a single one. So here you need to create a stream of collections, and then create a stream from each of them:

```
processeditemList.values().stream()
    .map(Map::keySet)     // Stream<Set<Item>>
    .flatMap(Set::stream) // convert each set to a stream
    .collect(toList());   // convert to list, this will be an ArrayList implmentation by default
```

If you want to change default List implementation, then you can use below collector:

```
Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new)
```

LinkedList would be good if you do not know the final size of the list, and you do more insert operations than read.

ArrayList is the oposite: more you read, and less add/remove. Because ArrayList under the hood holds an array, which must be rescaled when adding new elements, but never get's reduced, when you remove elements.

Comment: up-vote first, I like this form better than Jacob G's. but the OP who want to collect items into a LinkedList.

Comment: [Why is ArrayDeque better than LinkedList](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163166/why-is-arraydeque-better-than-linkedlist)

Comment: The reasoning is nonsense. Whether you know the final size of the list, is irrelevant. And even if you are going to do more insert operations than read, the `ArrayList` will be faster in most practical use cases. But even if it is slower in some insertions, you will rarely have write-only data structures in applications, so the subsequent processing will more than compensate the insertion costs, if they really are higher.

Answer (score 17):

I'm on my phone at the moment so I can't promise that this will be syntactically perfect, but here's how you can do it with a `Stream`:

```
processeditemList.values().stream()
    .flatMap(e -> e.keySet().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new));
```

I'm unable to test it currently, but I'll look over the Javadocs and change anything if it's incorrect.

Edit: I think everything is good.  If it doesn't matter which `List` implementation is used, you can change

```
Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new)
```

to

```
Collectors.toList()
```