# Kotlin : Interface Queue does not have constructors

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to instantiate an object of `Queue` using below code

`var queue: Queue<Int> = Queue()`

But I get this

> Interface Queue does not have constructors

No idea what's going on, while searching I found this [link.](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-7770)

But I don't understand anything.
Please help.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`Queue` is an [interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html). So you can't instantiate an interface, you have to implement it or instantiate a class that implement it.

For example, you can do `var queue: Queue<Int> = ArrayDeque<Int>()`. [ArrayDeque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) implements `Queue`.

Comment: This will be then a deque not queue I guess?

Comment: `Deque` extends `Queue`

Comment: Hmm, after going through multiple stackoverflow questions, what I figured out is there are various implementations of the Queue interface. Now my problem is which one should I use. I just want a really basic queue. Should I go with ArrayDeque or LinkedList?

Comment: `ArrayDeque` is the choice to go for in doubt, because LinkedLists carry significant overhead that is only justified in rare cases: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163166/why-is-arraydeque-better-than-linkedlist/6163204#6163204

Answer (score 14):

You trying to create instance of interface but don`t override methods for it. You should use something like this:

```
val queueA = LinkedList<Int>()
val queueB = PriorityQueue<Int>()
```

Also you can read more about queue implementations [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/queue.html)

Answer (score 3):

Queue is an interface. So you can't instantiate an interface. You should use something like this:

```
val queue: Queue<Int> = LinkedList()
```