# ArrayDeque vs LinkedList as Queue for level-order traversal

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, queue

Is it true that `ArrayDeque` should be preferred over `LinkedList` in this scenario?
[Why is ArrayDeque better than LinkedList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163166/why-is-arraydeque-better-than-linkedlist).

In my opinion, I should be using LinkedList instead of ArrayDeque, as there are quite a lot of `poll` and `offer`
operation going on in this algorithm, and there is no random access to elements.

```
 public ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> levelOrder(TreeNode a) {
    Queue<TreeNode> q = new LinkedList<>();  // new ArrayDeque<>() ???
    q.offer(a);
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> ans = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    while (q.peek() != null){ //returns null if empty
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        int n = q.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            TreeNode node = q.poll();
            list.add(node.val);
            if (node.left != null) {
                q.offer(node.left);
            }
            if (node.right != null) {
                q.offer(node.right);
            }
        }
        ans.add(list);
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Comment: The first answer in the link you added explaining very well why you should use `ArrayDeque`, and when you should use `LinkedList`. I nearly marked it a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use LinkedList over ArrayList in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist-in-java)

Answer (score 10):

There are a number of tradeoffs to consider when deciding between `ArrayDeque` and `LinkedList` when treating the two as a doubly-ended queue.

Generally speaking, the `LinkedList` type has the following advantages:

- The cost of adding an element is worst-case O(1), so no individual insertion will ever take too much time.
- The cost removing an element from the ends is worst-case O(1), so no individual deletion will ever take too much time.

Generally speaking, the `LinkedList` type has the following major disadvantage:

- Because elements in a `LinkedList` are not necessarily stored contiguously in memory, the `LinkedList` has poor locality of reference, and accesses may result in more cache misses, decreasing performance.

Generally speaking, the `ArrayDeque` type has the following advantages:

- Because elements are stored contiguously, the `ArrayDeque` has great **locality of reference**, so element accesses will typically create few cache misses and thus lead to excellent performance.

Generally speaking, the `ArrayDeque` has the following disadvantage:

- Although any sequence of n operations on an `ArrayDeque` will take time O(n), when the array capacity is exceeded on an insertion, the `ArrayDeque` may have to do O(n) work to copy elements. As a result, the worst-case performance of an `ArrayDeque` per operation is slower than a `LinkedList`.
- Similarly, if the array capacity drops too low on a deletion, it may take time O(n) to resize the array, though, as before, any series of n operations on an `ArrayDeque` will take time O(n).

In your particular use case, since all you care about is the end-to-end efficiency of the level-order traversal, not the cost of any individual addition or removal of elements from the queue, it will probably be faster to use an `ArrayDeque` than a `LinkedList`. In a sense, the `LinkedList` type is generally only better if you need to have good worst-case performance on each operation performed, and that isn't the case here. The `ArrayDeque` is generally more performant when all you care about is end-to-end runtime.

Hope this helps!