# Merge 2 lists based on original ordering from the input list - JAVA

Tags: java, dictionary, for-loop, arraylist, java-8

I have a following function:

```
List<Pair<SomeObject, Integer>> process(List<SomeObject> input) {
   List<Pair<SomeObject, Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
   List<SomeObject> couldBeProcessed = new ArrayList<>();

   for (SomeObject obj : input) {
      if (couldBeProcessed(obj)) {
         couldBeProcessed.add(obj);
      } else {
         result.add(Pair.of(obj, 0));
      }
   }

   List<Pair<SomeObject, Integer>> processResult = processInBatch(couldBeProcessed); 
   // TODO: merge processResult with result here
}
```

How do I add this `processResult` into `results` but preserve the ordering as it was given to me in the `input`?

Comment: what are you creating the `Pair`s for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a map to hold the index and then good 'ol for loop:

```
List<Pair<SomeObject, Integer>> process(List<SomeObject> input) {
   List<Pair<SomeObject, Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
   Map<Integer, Pair<SomeObject, Integer>> map = new HashMap();
   List<SomeObject> couldBeProcessed = new ArrayList<>();

   for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
      if (couldBeProcessed(input.get(i))) {
         couldBeProcessed.add(obj);
      } else {
         map.put(i, Pair.newInstance(obj, 0));
      }
   }

   List<Pair<SomeObject, Integer>> processResult = processInBatch(couldBeProcessed); 

   for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
      if (map.containsKey(i)) {
         result.add(map.get(i));
      } else {
         result.add(processResult.remove(0));
      }
   }
}
```

You can also use [`Map#computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent(K,java.util.function.Function)) to make the second loop more compact:

```
for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
    result.add(map.computeIfAbsent(i, index -> processResult.remove(0));
}
```

P.S.: The elements of `processResult` must have the same indices as respective objects from the original list.

@Misha suggests a more natural way to handle the processed queue - by using `Deque`:

```
Deque<Pair<SomeObject, Integer>> processResult = new ArrayDeque(processInBatch(couldBeProcessed)); 

for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
    if (map.containsKey(i)) {
        result.add(map.get(i));
    } else {
        result.add(processResult.removeFirst());
    }
}
```

Comment: I really like this idea especially using `computeIfAbsent`. Thank you! I will use this.

Comment: @test123 I am superhappy I could help! Have a great day!

Comment: Instead of repeatedly calling `remove(0)` it's better to make `Deque<...> que = new ArrayDeque<>(processResult);`. Then you call `que.removeFirst()`, which will then avoid moving the entire backing array on every call.

Comment: @Misha yes, that feels much better, thank you. I have added that note in my answer, I hope it's ok

Comment: @Andronicus Please use `ArrayDeque` instead of `LinkedList`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163166/why-is-arraydeque-better-than-linkedlist and other linked answers.

Comment: @Misha huh, I didn't know that, thank you very much!

Comment: @Andronicus we can still use `computeIfAbsent`, is that correct?

Comment: @Misha thank you! One question though: Why `Deque`? Could I use `Queue` instead? Since I don't really need to remove from last?

Comment: @test123 Sure.  Makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Few suggestions possible with the current implementations inlined:

```
List<Pair<SomeObject, Integer>> process(List<SomeObject> input) {

    // use an index map if the initial order matters
    Map<SomeObject, Integer> indexMap = IntStream.range(0, input.size())
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(input::get, Function.identity()));

    // to split to either 'true' or 'false' you can use partitioning 
    Map<Boolean, List<SomeObject>> partitioned = input.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(this::couldBeProcessed));

    List<Pair<SomeObject, Integer>> result = partitioned.get(Boolean.FALSE).stream()
            .map(some -> Pair.of(some, 0))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    List<SomeObject> couldBeProcessed = partitioned.get(Boolean.TRUE);

    List<Pair<SomeObject, Integer>> processResult = processInBatch(couldBeProcessed);

    // while merging use the index from initial phases
    return Stream.concat(processResult.stream(), result.stream())
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(e -> indexMap.get(e.getLeft())))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Though the point of using `Pair` is still unclear in your complete approach and you might be able to get rid of it as well.

Comment: I can't create `Map<SomeObject, Integer>` unfortunately because of performance issues. `SomeObject` is very expensive to compute `hashCode`. Should've mentioned this in my original question.