# Which queue-derived data type could facilitate the fastest algorithm to check if an string is a palindrome?

Tags: java, queue, palindrome, deque, arraydeque

I am wondering if using Deque data structure implemented by ArrayDeque could offer better performance in terms of time complexity compared to the queue implemented by an array or a linked list?

As far as I have understood, both implementations could be O(n) in the worst_case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is ArrayDeque better than LinkedList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163166/why-is-arraydeque-better-than-linkedlist)

Comment: `LinkedList` is never the answer to “fastest” anything. It has poor memory performance characteristics, hampering whatever theoretical benefit it might have. Moreover the fastest way to check for a palindrome is to loop over the `String` directly.