# Passing both generic-type List<T> and different elements T (integer/boolean/character) to a single method in java

Tags: java, generics

I want to create the method that accepts both the Generic element type (`T t`) and its list (`List tList`), and adds the element to the list.

I get the error:

```
The method addDataToList(T, List) in the type IteratorExample is not applicable for the arguments (String, List)
```

```
public class IteratorExample {
    public static <T> void main(String[] args) {

        List<T> tList = new LinkedList<>();
        addDataToList("First Element", tList);
        addDataToList("String", tList);
        addDataToList(100986, tList);
        addDataToList(1.98F, tList);
        addDataToList(1009L, tList);
        addDataToList('x', tList);
    }

    static <T> void addDataToList(T t, List<T> tList) {
        tList.add(t);
    }
}
```

Comment: First, your main method should not be generic. What exactly are you trying to do here? You want to add string, int, long, floating point, char in the list, why not just use `List<Object>`?

Answer (score 1):

Every class is a subtype of `Object`. If you want to have a List of everything, make it `List<Object>`. Primitive types are not objects, but when calling a method which requires an argument of type `Object` *and* doesn't provide an overload for the appropriate primitive, the primitive gets auto-boxed to its representative boxed type (e.g. int -> Integer) which then gets downcasted to `Object` such that it fits the type of the parameter.

```java
List<Object> myEverythingBagel = new ArrayList<Object>();
myEverythingBagel.add(1);
myEverythingBagel.add("String");
// etc.
```

That is how you could do that, but the bigger question is **why would you want to do that?**

An everything-bagel collection can consume anything but will cause trouble when reading from it. Rather consider having dedicated collections for your different values.

Or better yet, when you have a relationship between those values, like `name` and `age` introduce a dedicated type for that entity. And for that take a look at Java records.

```java
record Person(String name, int age)
```

Then you can store these people in a `List<Person> people` instead.

## Tangent

Having a method parameter `List<T> list` is for when you want to pass differently typed Lists into the same method.

Keeping this method or it having generic parameters is not necessary when the initially created one is of type `List<Object>`. Because you just can call `list.add(value)` on it directly.

If you want to keep your "addDataToList" method (you could have planned it to do some logging or have other logic), you could change its signature to the following:

```java
static <T> void addDataToList(Object t, List<Object> tList) {
    tList.add(t);
}
```

And your main method shouldn't be generic.

## 2nd Tangent

Forget that `LinkedList`s exists. They are only academically interesting when teaching data structures.

Most of the time you would want to use an `ArrayList` or if you want to represent a Stack/Queue take a look at `ArrayDeque` it implements the same Interface (`Deque` = Double-ended Queue) as LinkedList but [performs much better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32646284/7082956).

Comment: Why is your suggested method in Tangent 1 generic? You don't use T.

Comment: @AndyTurner, I suspected OP of having issues with generic collections in the first place, which I tried to address in the main body of the answer. And as mentioned in the tangent the method as-is is redundant.

Comment: It's not redundant in OP's declaration, though: that method could be called with a `List<Object>`, a `List<String>` etc (given a compatible `t`, ofc). The problem isn't there, it's that OP creates a `List<T>` in the main method, and then tries to invoke the method with non-compatible values of `t` (just as you couldn't invoke `tList.add("...");` directly).

Comment: @AndyTurner If your tList is of generic type `Object` you surely can invoke `tList.add("...");` Everything is either of type object or will be auto-boxed to object. I will stand to my observation that the `addDataToList` method is redundant when the only collection concerning is of type `Object`.