# Which collection to use for critical remove in front and add at end?

Tags: java

I'm implementing an algorithm that will add strings at the end a collection and remove strings at the beginning. In rare cases I will perform random access remove to push it at the end. I'm  mostly a C++ dev, and I'm not sure what will be good to use in my critical loop in java. I don't think a java list will be well suited for the task. Sure it will work, but I'm already struggling with performance issues.

linked list? vector? suggestions?

Comment: `Vector` is the synchronized version of `ArrayList`. So consider using ArrayList, LinkedList whatever but not Vector. It's only useful when you need the synchronization.

Comment: I have threads so synch. will be required.

Comment: When you really need a thread-safe implementation then you should have mentioned this. The accepted answer is promoting `ArrayDeque` which is not thread-safe like most of the Collection classes. Even when you need synchronization you most likely need external sync anyway. There are rare use-cases for thread-safe collection classes like Vector. You say: "Perform random access remove to push it at the end". These are two operations that must be done in one sync scope. This cannot be acomplished by thread-safe impl. So you've to sync externally and are better with an impl that is not thread-safe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend using `ArrayDeque`, which implements `Queue` and [`Deque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) interfaces but doesn't implement `List` (which you probably won't need):

> Resizable-array implementation of the `Deque` interface. Array deques
>   have no capacity restrictions; they grow as necessary to support
>   usage. They are not thread-safe; in the absence of external
>   synchronization, they do not support concurrent access by multiple
>   threads. Null elements are prohibited. This class is likely to be
>   faster than `Stack` when used as a stack, and faster than `LinkedList`
>   when used as a queue.

You also mentioned remove:

> This interface provides two methods to remove interior elements,
>   `removeFirstOccurrence` and `removeLastOccurrence`.

`ArrayDeque` provides all methods you'll need - `addFirst(E e)`, `addLast(E e)`, `removeFirst()`.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129805/what-is-the-fastest-java-collection-with-the-basic-functionality-of-a-queue) to know more about `ArrayDeque`.

P.S. And here is [some collections benchmark](http://microbenchmarks.appspot.com/run/limpbizkit@gmail.com/com.publicobject.blog.TreeListBenchmark) from above link featuring `ArrayDeque`, `LinkedList` and `ArrayList` mentioned by others ;)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to implement a Queue (LIFO).  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html. You can check the source code and how it is implemented to get more ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want a queue, yes? Check out the [`Queue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) interface.

```
Queue<String> strQueue = new LinkedList<String>();
strQueue.offer("Hello");
strQueue.offer("World");
System.out.println(strQueue.poll());
System.out.println(strQueue.poll());
```

Prints:

```
Hello
World
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no point in using a Vector over an ArrayList unless you need all of the individual operations to be `synchronized`, which often one does not.

If you are only going to do head and tail insertions/removals, then a LinkedList makes the most sense. However if the list is large and you need to do random-access retrievals, then having to traverse the list could be a big pain.

On the other hand ArrayList offers very cheap random-access but inserting or removing elements from the head of the list requires the rest of the backing array to be moved. The JDK implementation does this by calling `System.arraycopy()`, which be able to do it very cheaply.

The best idea in a case like this is to benchmark using both implementations and comparing the results. Write the algorithm in question to just use a `List` and you can easily swap in different `List` implementations for your benchmark.

I don't see what the purpose of using a regular array over an ArrayList would be, as you would have to code the head/tail removal/insertions yourself and deal with resizing the array when the size grows over the capacity, all of which ArrayList already does for you.

Answer (score 1):

`java.util.ArrayDeque` supports queue operations using a circular buffer, which will probably be the most efficient approach for adding at the end and removing at the beginning, but it doesn't support random access by index - you can't remove the entry at index *n* other than by traversing the iterator.  There are methods to remove the first/last occurrence of a particular *value* but these internally do a linear search.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by a java list. The problem you describe sounds like a classic case for a LinkedList. The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) specifies that 'All of the operations perform as could be expected for a doubly-linked list'. This means that inserting an object at the end, as well as removing one from the beginning, is done in O(1), meaning that it takes the same time no matter how many elements you have in the list. Random access, however, is more difficult, and should be done in O(N), meaning the time is proportional to the actual number of elements in the list.

Of course, depending on the number of elements you have, a linked list with O(1) might not give the best time. For example, if you only expect a few elements in the list, then perhaps a data structure with an O(N) add/remove time, but faster accessors, might actually perform better. But for larger structures, the LinkedList class is probably the place to start.