# Implementing Cache with ArrayDeque

Tags: java, generics

**Introduction**

I've implemented a simple Cache with an LRU policy using an `ArrayDeque` and following a  `Generics` solution:

```
public class Cache<T> extends ArrayDeque<T> implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int MAX_SIZE;

    public Cache(int maxSize) {
        MAX_SIZE = maxSize;
    }

    public void store(T e) {
        if (super.size() >= MAX_SIZE) {                 
            this.pollLast();
        }
        this.addFirst(e);       
    }

    public T fetch(T e) {
        Iterator<T> it = this.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            T current = it.next();
            if (current.equals(e)) {
                this.remove(current);
                this.addFirst(current);
                return current;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

---

**Problem**

When I instantiate the class and push an element,

```
Cache<CachedClass> cache = new Cache<CachedClass>(10);
cache.store(new CachedClass());
```

at this point the queue does not contain anything.

Why is this happening?

---

**Observation**

By the way, the `CachedClass` overrides the method `.equals()`.

---

**Tests**

```
 public class CacheTest {

    @Test
    public void testStore() {
        Cache<Integer> cache = new Cache<Integer>(3);

        cache.store(1);
        assertTrue(cache.contains(1));

        cache.store(2);
        cache.store(3);
        cache.store(4);

        assertEquals(cache.size(), 3);      
    }

    @Test
    public void testFetch() {
        Cache<Context> cache = new Cache<Context>(2);

        Context c1 = new Context(1);
        Context c2 = new Context(2);

        cache.store(c1);
        cache.store(c2);                

        assertEquals((Context) cache.peekFirst(), (new Context(2)));

        Context c = cache.fetch(c1);

        assertTrue(c == c1);        
        assertEquals(cache.size(), 2);
        assertEquals((Context) cache.peekFirst(), (new Context(1)));

    }

 }
```

**EDIT** It passes both tests successfully.

> It passes the first test. It fails throwing an `AssertException` on
>
> ```
> assertTrue(cache.peekFirst() == 1);
> ```
>
> of the second test,

Comment: Setting a static variable in a constructor is not good practice. But this is not part of your problem.

Comment: How do you determine, that the queue is not containing anything?

Comment: Does CachedClass overrides equals?

Answer (score 1):

The Javadoc for LinkedHashMap says

> "This kind of map is well-suited to building LRU caches."

You really need a good reason to ignore this. My guess is that performance will be indistinguishable between the implementations on puts and much better on gets with the Map - but hey, why don't you run your own benchmark.

Finally your implementation (as well as the one provided by LinkedHashMap) is not thread safe. If this is an issue for you, the synchronisation logic will add performance overhead.

Comment: +1: I'll take your and @Peter Lawrey advice. Thanks. By the way, what kind of extra logic would I need to make it thread-safe?

Comment: For the LinkedHashMap have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap%28java.util.Map

Answer (score 0):

I do this in a main method:

```
    Cache<Integer> cache = new Cache<Integer>(10);
    cache.store(new Integer(0)); 
    System.out.println(cache.size()); // prints 1
    Integer foo = cache.fetch(new Integer(0));
    System.out.println(foo == null); // prints false
```

and it prints 1, so there is 1 element in your `Cache`. Works fine.

For fetching your `CachedClass` muss override `equals()`. Your code works perfectly as intended without a change.

Answer (score 0):

I use a LinkedHashMap as an LRU cache.

```
public static <K,V> Map<K,V> lruCache(final int maxSize) {
    return new LinkedHashMap<K,V>(maxSize*4/3, 0.75f, true) {
        @Override
        protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<K,V> eldest) {
            return size() > maxSize;
        }
    };
}
```

An important difference is that a key is associated with a value. If you implement a cache as a set all you can do is confirm an object you already have is in the cache or not, which is not as useful IMHO.

Tests

```
@Test
public void testStore() {
    Map<Integer, String> cache = lruCache(3);
    cache.put(1, "one");
    assertEquals("one", cache.get(1));

    cache.put(2, "two");
    cache.put(3, "three");
    cache.put(4, "four");

    assertEquals(cache.size(), 3);
    assertEquals(null, cache.get(1));
}

@Test
public void testFetch() {
    Map<Integer, String> cache = lruCache(3);

    cache.put(1, "one");
    cache.put(2, "two");

    assertEquals((Integer) 1, cache.keySet().iterator().next());

    String s = cache.get(1);

    assertEquals("one", s);
    assertEquals(cache.size(), 2);
    assertEquals((Integer) 2, cache.keySet().iterator().next());
}
```

Comment: I think that the main point of caching is speed. I used ArrayDeque because is the fastest collection (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129805/what-is-the-fastest-java-collection-with-the-basic-functionality-of-a-queue). My idea is that, when fetching, by iterating over the elements, you get the advantatge of LRU. I see your point but extra features are added as fields in the ChachedClass.

Comment: A lookup with LHM is O(1) whereas a lookup with ArrayDeque is O(N) so I don't see how it its faster.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, but what about storing/fetching? ArrayDeque is O(1) for remove/add. And for lookup you start from head and hopefully LRU will perform right for a given problem.

Comment: ArrayDeque is O(1) for remove of the first element, otherwise it is O(N).  Instead of hoping, I would use a collection is is not just O(1) but does the get+remove+add in one operation which will simplify things if you want to make it thread safe. ;)