# ArrayDeque vs ArrayList to implement a stack

Tags: java, arraylist, stack, arraydeque

The documentation for `ArrayDeque` says:

> This class is likely to be faster than Stack when used as a stack, and faster than LinkedList when used as a queue.

There is no mention of the difference between using an `ArrayDeque` as a stack and using an `ArrayList`. You can use an `ArrayList` as a stack as follows.

```
list.add(object);                      // push
object = list.remove(list.size() - 1); // pop
```

I found that when I used an `ArrayList` in this way only, its performance is worse than `ArrayDeque`. What accounts for this difference? Surely, it can't just be the calls to `size()`? Internally, both `ArrayList` and `ArrayDeque` are implemented using an `Object[]` that is replaced by a larger array when required, so surely the performance should be about the same?

Comment: Good explanation here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129805/what-is-the-fastest-java-collection-with-the-basic-functionality-of-a-queue

Comment: Measuring such a presumably tiny performance difference in Java is extremely hard to do right. And ArrayDeque is a better abstraction anyway than an ArrayList, since it directly offers push and pop methods.

Comment: @JBNizet I agree. I would always use `ArrayDeque`. I'm just interested to understand what an `ArrayDeque` is. How can it support quick insertion and removal at both ends and yet beat data types that don't support this?

Comment: Sorry for my confusing answer, I thought you were taking the element from the head.

Comment: @Augusto No worries. You had me worried there. I do make really silly maths mistakes at times!

Comment: I've just read an implementation of `ArrayDeque` and found it be a circular buffer. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer

Comment: On recent implementations, depending on how you instantiate the ArrayList, it may defer the allocation of the internal array until the first add call. Maybe that may account for some of the difference.

Comment: My guess, as your performance test code is missing, is that your performance test is faulty. There are many variables at play during a perf test and unless you are using a tool like JMH, you are most likely doing it wrong. Also, unless you are worried about micros, I would go with ArrayDeque which has a cleaner interface for a stack. If you are trying to save micros, use a plan array.

Answer (score 50):

The main difference between both implementation is the resize strategy

- `ArrayList` is resized to a new size of `oldCapacity + (oldCapacity >> 1)`, resulting in an increse of ~50%. The default capacity is 10, resulting in a capacities after resize of 15, 22, 33, 49, 73, 109, 163, 244, 366...
- `ArrayDeque` is always resized to a power of 2. On resize, the capacity is doubled. Starting with the default of 16, the resuling capacities after resize are 32, 64, 128, 256,...

So the ArrayDeque reaches higher capacities with much less resize operation, which are costly because of array copy. I.e. to store 256 in default-sized ArrayList, it requires 9 resize calls, while the ArrayDeque only need 4.
Array copy may be fast, but may also require a GC to free some space for the new data sets, in addition to the memory copy costs (where the ArrayDeque might also perform better due to it's alignment to power-of-2).

Both datastructures have best-case complexity of O(1) for push and pop through direct access on either `head` & `tail` (ArrayDequeue) respectively add and remove(Last)  `size` (ArrayList)

Answer (score 1):

#### To answer the question, let's compare the remove methods of the ArrayList and ArrayDeque classes.

**ArrayList remove method**

```
public E remove(int index) {
    this.rangeCheck(index);
    ++this.modCount;
    E oldValue = this.elementData(index);
    int numMoved = this.size - index - 1;
    if (numMoved > 0) {
        System.arraycopy(this.elementData, index + 1, this.elementData, index, numMoved);
    }

    this.elementData[--this.size] = null;
    return oldValue;
}
```

**ArrayDeque removeLast method**

```
 public E removeLast() {
    E x = this.pollLast();
    if (x == null) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    } else {
        return x;
    }
}
```

**ArrayDeque removeLast method calling pollLast method**

```
    public E pollLast() {
    int t = this.tail - 1 & this.elements.length - 1;
    E result = this.elements[t];
    if (result == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        this.elements[t] = null;
        this.tail = t;
        return result;
    }
}
```

**Let's explain the ArrayList remove method step by step:**

1. Check if the entered index is within the limits of the array
2. Increment the ModCount variable by one.
3. Store the value to be deleted.
4. Determine how many numbers to move (in our example, numMoved 0 is found because the last element will be deleted).
5. Copy the array if the number to move is greater than 0 (the copy will not be performed because numMoved 0 is found).
6. Assign null to the last element of the array.
7. Return the deleted value.

**Let's explain the ArrayDeque removeLast method step by step (it will suffice to explain the pollLast method):**

1. Find the last index of the array
2. Return the value of the last element of the array.
3. Return null if the value of the last element is equal to null.
4. İf the value of the last element is not null (if it is not null, the following steps will occur).
5. Assign null to last element
6. Update the value of the tail variable
7. Return result

**When we compare the steps, there is no noticeable difference in terms of performance**. In our example, `ArrayList's System.copyarray`  method will not work because we deleted the last element. If this method had worked, there would have been a performance difference. In conclusion there is no difference to be considered other than [@Gerald Mücke's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45793227/18248169). **If the element to be deleted was the first element of the list then there would be a performance difference.** When we want to delete the first element, we can use the `removeFirst` method of the `ArrayDeque` class. (The `removeFirst` method works similarly to the `removeLast` method). When we want to delete the first element in ArrayList, we can use the `remove(0)` method. When we delete the ArrayList with 0 index, this time the array copy(`System.copyarray`) will be done. We used to say that `ArrayList` is slower because of the array copying process.