# Performance of ArrayList vs ArrayDeque while implementing stack

Tags: java

I have some doubt regarding this behavior.I assume performance of ArrayList would be same as ArrayDeque while implementing stack as ArrayDeque will use its addLast() method for insertion and removeLast() for deletion.Both will be equally efficient in this case.Please correct me if I am wrong somewhere.

Comment: Why don't you test that behavior?

Answer (score 3):

When used as stack, `ArrayDeque` and `ArrayList`'s performance should be almost the same. Both "push" would be amortized O(1), though their initial capacity might have a slightly affect on the performance.

The [default capacity for `ArrayList` is 10](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList()), while the [initial capacity of `ArrayDeque` is 16](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html#ArrayDeque()). Their internal growth policies cause small performance difference which might not be noticable in practice. You can refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31377200/3697757) for more information.

After all, their "push" operation is amortized O(1).

** This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6129967/3697757) mentions `ArrayDeque`'s javadoc suggests that it may be slightly faster, but I haven't found the source.

Answer (score 0):

They are both amorized O(1) with stack operation. The main difference is:

1. ArrayDeque is resized by factor 2, while ArrayList is 1.5
2. The initial capacity of ArrayDeque is 16, while ArrayList is 10

So when using them to to store 1024 elements, ArrayDeque calls 6 resize methods, while the ArrayList only calls 12 methods, nealy 2 times of the ArrayDeque.