# About implementation of ArrayDeque in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, arraydeque

The documentation says:

> Resizable-array implementation of the Deque interface. Array deques
>   have no capacity restrictions; they grow as necessary to support usage

However I still want to understand what exactly the structure of ArrayDeque is, how the resizing works. Also it would be great if someone could provide a reliable source where I can find the answer. According to some of the Google results I found, it is possibly implemented as a circular array. Is it true?  And what is the grow policy? Is it similar to ArrayList? If it is, does ArrayDeque have a similar performance to ArrayList in the operations like adding or removing the element at the end?

Thank you.

Comment: Read the source code?

Comment: @chrylis Yes I'm doing it now. It seems to me that it is a circular array. And the size doubles when it is full, which makes the grow policy very similar to ArrayList. I don't understand why many people say ArrayDeque is faster than ArrayList.

Comment: Who says it's faster? They're different kinds of data structures, not alternative implementations.

Comment: For adding elements at the _beginning_, ArrayDeque is going to be faster because if it doesn't need resizing, it will just decrement the head counter (possibly wrapping around) . ArrayList will copy over all elements to n+1. But fit adding at the end, they should be pretty similar.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The grow policy of `ArrayList` and `ArrayDeque` is not documented and may vary between JDK implementations and even JDK versions. For example, in [Open JDK 6](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.ensureCapacity%28int%29) it was `(n*3/2+1)`, but in [Open JDK 8](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.grow%28int%29) it's `(n*3/2)`. Also in JDK 6 `ArrayList` with default constructor was initially created with 10 elements array while in JDK 8 it allocates an array only when at least one element is added.

The [`ArrayDeque`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/ArrayDeque.java/) implementation changes less often than `ArrayList`. It always uses internally the power-of-two sized array starting with `16` by default and doubling it when necessary, thus memory footprint may be different for `ArrayList` and `ArrayDeque` (for `ArrayDeque` you will have in average less reallocations, but more wasted memory).

Addition to the tail is roughly equally fast for both `ArrayList` and `ArrayDeque` unless reallocation is necessary. Reallocation events may occur at different points. For example, by default first reallocation for `ArrayList` will occur when adding element #11, but for `ArrayDeque` it will occur on element #16.

The advantage of `ArrayDeque` is ability to add/remove elements to the head as fast as to the tail. In contrast, `ArrayList` will do it in `O(n)` time as it will have to move all the existing elements. Thus use `ArrayDeque` when you need to add/remove both to head and tail. If you need to modify the tail only, usually `ArrayList` is preferred.