# Java collection performance when comparing items

Tags: java, performance, collections, equals, identity

A basic performance question from someone coming from C/C++.

I'm using a Collection (`ArrayDeque`) to simply hold, add, remove items by identity. I know the contract is for the collection to use `equals()` when checking equality, for example during `remove(obj)`, but in my case I want to use reference semantics (like IdentityHashMap but don't need the map). So I am fine to just *know* that I will never override the `equals()` on any of the objects held inside the collection (which is declared to hold an interface).

Coming from native programming I can't avoid asking myself, will the compiled code of `remove(obj)` traverse items and perform a *virtual call* on `Object.equals()` only to end up comparing addresses? Since I'm storing interface references, there is no way (?) to optimise this using `final` so the compiler doesn't bother making the useless calls (i.e. inline them) - but now I'm getting ahead of myself because it may be such optimisation is not necessary anyway and JVM has other means (devirtualisation?) to generate optimal code in this case.

Assuming my code needs the level of optimisation that can be obtained by thinking about this aspect in the first place - **is my understanding correct? What is a good design for this case**?

Comment: You can expect that the call to `Object::equals` will get inlined by the JIT compiler if it's called repeatedly ==> don't bother.

Comment: @assylias but that's tricky right? For all the compiler knows, that collection might contain multiple most-derived class instances, some of which might override `equals()` and some not. So it's impossible to generate code that will not look at each item individually - inlining requires an assumption that needs to be expressed compile-time

Comment: Inlining does need compile-time assumption for the JVM - it's the whole point of JIT compiling: it uses all the information available at runtime. You can run your program with the following options to see if and when the method gets inlined: `-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintInlining`

Comment: I see, that's useful

Comment: What I meant, I'm sure you saw it, was "Inlining does NOT need", duh.

Comment: The whole idea of Java is that you don't need to care about this kind of details. I guess that by *virtual call* you mean the traditional C++ style. [Here are the (quite overwhelming and startling) low-level details](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/HotSpot/VirtualCalls).

Comment: You are using an `ArrayDeque`, a collection optimized for removal at the ends (not somewhere in the middle), invoke `remove(Object)` on it, and are worrying about the performance of the `equals` invocation, rather than the array copying? A really good example of premature optimization heading into the wrong direction…

Comment: @Holger I did not mention the container would be small, or in other words, I want to optimise it for small usage. A contiguous container with elements that have reference semantics is therefore best suited, definitely better than something based on linked nodes which only performs well after a large number of elements. As a use case, think of maintaining a list of listeners into an observable, you need to add/remove listeners.

Comment: When the container is small, the number of `equals` operation is small as well, which makes it even less a performance issue. I’m surely not recommending a linked data structure, whose nodes would kill the performance even more when the container gets big. For bigger containers, a `HashSet` would make more sense. When the use case is like maintaining listeners, why did you chose `ArrayDeque`? Which of its properties do you really need? Do you need to maintain the order, do you need to change it at both ends (e.g. in contrast to `ArrayList`)?

Comment: @Holger the question isn't about _one container_ and certainly not about _ArrayDeque_ specifically. You might have multiple small containers such that the combined time spent by the application is significant. I think the question holds general value regardless of what containers you use and how large, _if_ the application has _many containers that require only identity-equals semantics_. As for the specific choice of `ArrayDeque` it was based on the accepted answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/q/6129805/1088790

Comment: That answer is correct for the question “What is the fastest Java collection with the basic functionality of a Queue?”, but why do you think you needed a queue? When you bring the large number of container into the view, then, we get back to square one. The array copying costs are significantly higher than the costs of the `equals` operations, so *if* there is a performance issue (you didn’t say there is an actual problem), you are looking at the wrong lever. It has been said already that JVMs are capable of optimizing such invocations (especially in a loop), but the copying will remain.

Comment: On the `ArrayDeque` - again, this is not central to the question; I can agree `ArrayList`is the better option, but then, the question still applies. As for _array copying costs are significantly higher than the costs of the equals operations_, this is not necessarily true: `remove()` from multiple small arrays are cheaper than removes from fewer larger arrays, because it means shifting shorter stretches of data, whereas, the application of `equals()` method is equally concerning for both smaller and larger arrays.

Comment: ... and on top of this, removes from a container of size <N (where N=8?) I would expect take the same time due to CPU architecture considerations (reads and writes are made in multiples of cache line size). The point I'm trying to make is, intuitively, an application where a lot of add-if-inexistent & remove operations are done on small, contiguous Object containers, the successive application of `equals()`, if not optimized somehow, is the worrying aspect (yes of course program efficiency should be tested in whole and yes of course _optimize late_, but the question, I think, stands to reason)

Answer (score 0):

Making the method `final` wont avoid the virtual call because `invokevirtual` opcode will be used anyway and there is no way for the JVM to tell if the method was final or not.

The good news is that the JVM might be able inline it or avoid the virtual call if it can't see that the method is overridden anywhere in the classpath so your performance will improve as your program runs.

Comment: Of course, a JVM can recognize whether a method is `final`. You [check it in your application code](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getModifiers--), so why should the JVM not be able to do it as well?

Answer (score 0):

When you use the remove method, it will call the equals method for comparison. Ideally, you should be overriding the equals and hashcode method to use such methods. Otherwise the by-default implementation of type-checking and address comparison happens. It is highly recommended to define your implementation of equals and hashcode methods while using methods of Collections. 
Regarding the performance, yes you are right - all the objects in the collection will be scanned linearly till the JVM encounters correct match. It is a linear search, hence the time complexity for this operation of removal will take O(n) time.

Comment: Why do you say I _should be overriding the equals and hashcode_? What I want is identity equality.

Comment: For identity equality, you need to tell Java how objects of a particular class should be compared. A class may have more than one fields. In that case Java does not know how to compare objects. By default, java will only compare the addresses and move on. However, if you want Java to compare the values, then you should tell Java the comparison logic. This comparison logic can be specified in the methods equals and hashcode.

Comment: respectfully, you don't know what _identity equality_ means. It means exactly to compare addresses. So, for _identity equality_, you don't need to tell Java anything.