# Does ArrayDeque have overhead of shifting elements on remove/add?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, queue, arraydeque

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129805/what-is-the-fastest-java-collection-with-the-basic-functionality-of-a-queue) question, where 1st (accepted) answer says this part:

> ArrayDeque doesn't have the overhead of node allocations that
> LinkedList does nor the overhead of shifting the array contents left
> on remove that ArrayList has.

I agree with *node overhead*, but not with the part about *shifting elements*. I know *StackOverflow* can also have wrong information, but this answer has many votes, so it must be my ignorance. So can someone tell me this:

Howcome `ArrayDeque` doesn't have overhead of *shifting elements*? `ArrayDeque` (as its name states) still uses an **ARRAY**. Meaning it works same as any other *array*. If I had 10 elements and I remove *head*, those 9 will have to be shifted 1 place to the left. And that is overhead that `LinkedList` doesn't have - it just changes reference to *prev* and *next*. Am I correct?

To sum, don't `ArrayList` and `ArrayDeque` work the same way? They both shift elements if structure gets changed. The only difference is that `ArrayList` can access any *arbitrary location*, while `ArrayDeque` works as *FIFO/LIFO*. Can someone please correct me if I am wrong? I don't want to learn something wrong here.

Comment: I'd say, you're right. But they only looked at the queue operations at the head of the structure, both in the post and the benchmark. Just had a look, ArrayDequeue also has e.g. `delete(i)` with all shift stuff going on, and it does it the same way like ArrayList (System.arrayCopy).

Comment: How could someone make a comment like that by just looking at operations on one queue's side? I just can't understand how many votes that answer got when its half true. Or is it actually.

Comment: well, that was the question of the OP, fair enough. But especially this linked list/array list discussion goes on forever, you can find hours long talks dissecting their specifics down to effects on the hardware level and what not.

Comment: on removing the first element `ArrayDequeue` has not to shift the remaining elements because `ArrayDequeue` has a field for the position of the first element (`head`). Removing the first element translates basically to `head++` (with some extra logic necessary if the value of `head` afterwards is the same as the length of the internal array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's great to have the intuition that removing from the front of an array will require everything to be shifted back. However, in the specific case of the `ArrayDeque`, the implementation is designed in a way that doesn't require this.

An array-based deque is typically implemented using a data structure called a ***circular buffer***. The idea is that we maintain an array of elements, but pretend that the ends of the array are glued together to form a ring.

The `ArrayDeque` internally maintains an array of 16 elements, which we can view like this:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

We maintain two different pointers, a *head pointer* and a *tail pointer*, keeping track of the position of the first element of the deque and the position one past the last element of the deque. Initially, they'll point to the start of the array:

```
 head
  |
  v
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  ^
  |
 tail
```

Whenever we do an `addFirst`, we back up the head pointer by one step, then write the element to the location we find. Since we're pretending that the two ends of the array are linked together, backing up one step here moves the head pointer to the last position:

```
                                                             head
                                                              |
                                                              v
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | X |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  ^
  |
 tail
```

To do an `addLast`, we write to the tail position, then advance it forward:

```
                                                             head
                                                              |
                                                              v
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| X |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | X |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
      ^
      |
     tail
```

Here's what it would look like if we did two more `addFirst`s:

```
                                                     head
                                                      |
                                                      v
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| X |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | X | X | X |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
      ^
      |
     tail
```

And here's what it would look like if we did two more `addLast`s:

```
                                                     head
                                                      |
                                                      v
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| X | X | X |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | X | X | X |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
              ^
              |
             tail
```

We read the elements of the deque by starting at the head pointer and proceeding forward until we reach the tail pointer. So in this case, we start reading from the slot pointed at by `head`, not the first position in the array.

Arranging things this way makes it very fast (O(1)) to remove the first element of the deque. We just clear out the entry pointed at by `head` and move `head` forward a step, like this:

```
                                                         head
                                                          |
                                                          v
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| X | X | X |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | X | X |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
              ^
              |
             tail
```

Notice that nothing needs to get shifted around, since we're just pretending that we start at a later position in the array.

However, were you to remove from the middle of the `ArrayDeque`, then, like removing from the middle of most other array-based structures, yes, you'd have to shift elements around. But, then again, `ArrayDeque` isn't optimized for that use case; it's specifically designed to be a double-ended queue, as the name suggests.