# ArrayList VS ArrayDeque in shifting elements?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, queue, arraydeque

I tried asking a similar question, but I failed to receive any satisfying answer. The motivation behind this question is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129805/what-is-the-fastest-java-collection-with-the-basic-functionality-of-a-queue)'s first (accepted) answer that roughly says:

> ArrayDeque doesn't have the overhead of shifting contents like ArrayList.

From my point of view, they should act the same. The only difference is that `ArrayList` is implemented from `List` interface, meaning it can access any *arbitrary index*. On the other side, `ArrayDeque` is implemented from `Queue` interface and it works in *LIFO/FIFO* manner.

The thing I want to point is that they both use **AN ARRAY** to store elements. Meaning if they both had an array with these elements:

```
2, 4, 6, 8, 10
```

, doing `arraylist.remove(0);` and `arraydeque.poll();` should both remove *first/head* element with value 2.

Now my big question. Do all those left numbers (4,6,8,10) get shifted to left for 1 slot in both cases? Is there any difference between `ArrayList` and `ArrayDeque` in way how they shift elements when we do any structure modification?

Comment: Recommend you learn how an array deque actually works!! See e.g. [Introduction to the Java ArrayDeque](https://www.baeldung.com/java-array-deque) *(Baeldung)*, [Circular array](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/circular-array/) *(GeeksforGeeks)*, [Circular buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) *(Wikipedia)*, [What is actually a circular array and representation](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/97451) *(Computer Science Stack Exchange)*, etc. --- They all have nice pictures to help you understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `ArrayList`, each of the elements gets shifted over.

In `ArrayDeque`, the elements *don't move* in the array.  The pointer in the array that says where the current head of the queue is  gets moved over.

(Why doesn't `ArrayList` do this, you might ask?  It could conceivably do it, but it'd only work for inserting/removing elements at the beginning and end, not in the middle.  `ArrayList` isn't really designed to be used that way -- if you're doing that, then you have a queue/deque, so you might as well use `ArrayDeque`.)

Comment: How they don't move if I removed 1st element? Meaning my 2nd element would take 1st place and so will the rest of elements have to shift? Can you clear it please? Regardless of the pointer, which is understandable.

Comment: @Stefan: I don't understand your question.  If you remove the first element of an ArrayList, yes, the second element moves to the first position, and all the other elements move one place too.

Comment: Sorry, I should had been more precise. I was asking that particular question for `ArrayDeque`. I mean how they don't move if I remove zero indexed element? Let's ignore cursor here for a second and focus on plain array.

Comment: The first element gets set to null.  The other elements don't move.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I made an ArrayDeque of size 100. Then I removed the first element using the removeFirst() method. Then I printed the array hoping I would see "null" as you mentioned in your comment but I did not see "null" there. It was an array where it looked like the elements were shifted. So can you please confirm whether they shift or not?

Comment: @LouisWasserman Also I just saw on java documentation that it says "Null elements are prohibited.". If null elements are prohibited in ArrayDeque then how/why does it get set to null instead of shifting?

Comment: You don't get to use null elements because it uses null for other reasons -- like marking unused space in the array.  When you "printed the array," you don't get to see the internal details of the ArrayDeque, only the values it lets you see.

Answer (score 1):

ArrayDeque maintains a small internal array of size 16, and maintains the pointer to head and tail until its size reach its limit. Once it reach it limits, it will double the size of the array. All the operations, we do on ArrayDeque are managed with head and tail pointers in hand.

But in case of ArrayList, majority of operations are using index of array. And it starts from  0. So in case of ArrayList it has to move all elements of ArrayList if we remove first  element from it to maintain its index. That is not a challenge for ArrayDeque, it can just update the pointer of tail or head depends on from where we are removing the item.

Comment: Okay, it changes the pointer position. But that element still has to be removed. Where do rest of the elements go then? What happens with zero index-ed element(head) once it gets removed in ArrayDeque?

Comment: Rest of elements stay wherever it was within ArrayDeque before the operation.

Comment: So I will still have array of size 5, just element at index 0 is now gone and pointer points to index 1? That means that if I keep removing elements from the head and pointer always points to next element, my array would grow infinitely. I must be missing something here.

Comment: Or actually I will have array of size 4 (head being removed), but elements never shift. Is that the correct point of view?

Comment: If you have only 4 elements within ArrayDeque, internally it will maintain an array of 16, but size() returns 4.. It is the difference of offset of head and tail pointer.

Comment: @Stefan: You will still have an array of size 5.  If you "keep removing elements from the head," then as soon as you've gone through all the elements, then it'll throw an exception and not let you remove any more elements.